# Adding an object in a pointer of vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to add an object in a vector of pointers:

```
vector<CCellDescr*> m_Data; // table contains(pointers to a cell)

void setCell(const CCellDescr& cell_Data)
{
    m_Data.push_back( cell_Data);
}
```

I try with `m_Data->push_back(cell_Data)` but it didn`t work. The error is:

```
Error 1 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(CCellDescr *&&)' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const CCellDescr' to 'CCellDescr *&&'
```

Comment: `m_Data.push_back(&cell_Data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a vector of pointers, but you are trying to push a reference to it. Try `m_Data.push_back(&cell_Data)`.